# XML converts to plaintext when data is pulled using WinForms. Is there a way to maintain the XML, or convert it back in C#?

Tags: c#, xml, winforms

I am creating a program that outputs relevant columns of SP_WhoIsActive in SQL Server, so that other members of my wider team who do not have access to the servers can see if there are any expensive queries running at the moment.

I have managed to create a WinForm that pulls the data, but unfortunately the XML Query has converted to plaintext, which essentially renders it useless as the text in one line is much too long.

How can I keep this as XML, with the first line of the XML as the link to the XML, or reconvert it back to XML if needed?

Thanks for your help in advance.

```
    connection = new SqlConnection(builder.ConnectionString))
                        {
    connection.Open();
    Console.WriteLine("Connected.");

    //Query
    Console.WriteLine("Executing Query");
    String sql = @"Truncate table [Reporting].dbo.Active_Processes
                    use master
                    EXEC sp_WhoIsActive
                        @output_column_list = '[[dd%][session_id][sql_text][sql_command][login_name][wait_info][tasks][tran_log%][cpu%][temp%][block%][reads%][writes%][context%][physical%][query_plan][locks][%]',
                        @destination_table = '[Reporting].dbo.Active_Processes'

                    IF OBJECT_ID('TEMPDB..#temp') IS NOT NULL
                    DROP    TABLE   #temp
                    select  session_id [SP ID]
                            , [dd hh:mm:ss.mss] Duration
                            , start_time [Start Time]
                            , database_name as [Database]
                            , @@SERVERNAME as [Server]
                            , login_name [Login]
                            , sql_text [Query]
                            , CPU 
                    --      , blocking_session_id [Blocked By]
                    into #temp
                    from    [Reporting].dbo.active_processes ap
                    --where [dd hh:mm:ss.mss] > '00 00:03:00.000'

                    select  [SP ID] as [Process]
                            ,c.[Name] as Project
                            ,convert(nvarchar,t.[Start Time],113) as [Query Start]
                            ,t.Duration as [Dy H M S Ms]
                            ,ISNULL(CPU,0) as CPU
                            ,t.Query
                    from #temp t
                    INNER JOIN   LPFOR1.EDDS.eddsdbo.[Case] c
                    on              'EDDS' + CAST(c.artifactid as varchar) = t.[Database]
                    --INNER JOIN   LPFOR1.EDDS.eddsdbo.ResourceServer rs
                    --on              rs.artifactid = c.serverid
                    order by [Dy H M S Ms] desc";


    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))

    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        // create data adapter
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
        // this will query your database and return the result to your datatable
        da.Fill(dt);
        this.grdSQLreport.DataSource = dt;
        da.Dispose();
```

Thank you.

[Image of XML Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W48nj.png)

Comment: I am not too familiar with this stored procedure (always used sp_who), assuming it is a bespoke one? Would it not be easier to read the results as a DataSet and then display/manipulate this accordingly? Also can you provide some example code and show where the XML is converted to plaintext?

Comment: Hi Ryan, thanks for a very quick response. sp_whoisactive is something I found that seems to be an upgrade of sp_who/who2: http://whoisactive.com. By DataSet, do you mean DataGridView? If so, that is what I am currently using. I have added the code that includes the XML (sql_txt [Query] and then t.Query). Running the SQL script on the server does output as XML still.

Comment: Does the DataTable (dt) look correct when it is populated? Is all the XML there? I imagine it is? I think it might be a limitation with the datagridview to display things just as text. I will see if I can come up with a suitable solution. :)

Comment: Yep, the DataTable looks correct when it's populated, all of the columns are there, it's only the Query column that's super long. I have attached an image above to illustrate. Great, thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per our conversation in the comments the problem is the limitations with the DataGridView to display text.

Now what I would do is to manually create the columns in design mode - you can use the DataPropertyName to bind to columns in the dataset/object (let me know if you need help with this)

Then I would create a button (or link - depending which style you prefer) column with the header of "Query" or similar and then you can handle the DataGridView CellContentClick method to show a new popup window with a RichTextEdit control or similar to display the XML. You can then bind this to the xml column and limit the size so it's click to show full or just have them all set to "Click to view" or something similar.

The below is messy example, you should tidy it up a little bit.

```
private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        var senderGrid = (DataGridView)sender;

        if (senderGrid.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "queryButtonColumn" &&
            e.RowIndex >= 0)
        {
            var xml = ((WhoIsActive)dataGridView1.CurrentRow.DataBoundItem).XmlCol;
            Form2 display = new Form2(xml);
            //Show dialog or normally accordingly...
            //display.Show();
            display.ShowDialog();

        }
    }
```

To format the string into XML when placing in a RichTextBox in the pop form you can do this.

```
public Form2(string text)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        richTextBox1.Text = System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Parse(text).ToString(); //This doesn't actually parse with your data from the query so just set it to the variable.
    }
```

Again I probably wouldn't use the data table directly here I would create a class for the WhoIsActive results and then have a variable which is a List of that type and use this as the DataSource of the DataGridView.

To do this create a class and add the appropriate properties.

```
public class WhoIsActive
{
    public string XmlCol { get; set; }
    public string Random { get; set; }
}
```

Then in your main form create a variable that is a List of these.

```
List<WhoIsActive> results = new List<WhoIsActive>();
```

Then when you read from the database you can populate this object and bind it to the datagrid.

```
adp.Fill(dt);

                foreach (DataRow item in dt.Rows)
                {
                    var plop = new WhoIsActive
                    {
                        Random = item["Random"].ToString(),
                        XmlCol = item["XmlCol"].ToString(),
                    };
                    results.Add(plop);
                }

                dataGridView1.DataSource = results;
```

Happy to edit this provide a more detailed example if required.

Comment: Hi Ryan, thank you very much for this. I'll give it a good go now, but if I'm struggling I may ask for further help. Thanks for helping me with this, it's greatly appreciated!

Comment: No worries, of course. I have updated my answer to use a class representation for the WhoIsActive results, hopefully this is better.

Comment: To further improve my answer in the CellContentClick you can change the if statement to if (senderGrid.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "queryButtonColumn") assuming you gave the column a sensible name. :)

Comment: You can also use a LinkColumn instead of a Button if you prefer this styling. This would allow you to achieve a similar styling to SSMS, by having a fixed width and then clicking it to show full.

Comment: Apologies for the spam! I also have a sample project I could upload somewhere, if you get stuck and would find this useful.

Comment: Not spam at all! If you could upload the sample project, that would be fab! It would be very useful for me.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/0r9fqeagnuuw3t7/WhoIsActiveDataGrid.zip?dl=0 should be able to download form here. Let me know if you get any problems.

Comment: Hi Ryan, this worked! Had a bit of a snag with the xml, as it didn't have a root element, so had to concatenate them on to make it work. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Ah yeah I had the same thing, I thought I updated my answer, but apparently not, apologies! In the end I just displayed it in a rich text box and it looked okay ha. Glad you sorted it! :)

Answer (score 0):

It appears as clickable XML in SQL Server Management Studio because SSMS auto-detects and formats XML in this manner. The default `DataGridView` has no such capabilities, as such you'd need to write a [custom cell renderer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellpainting) to achieve the same.